problemas con switch y String
Buenas con todos soy estudiante de ingenieria de sistemas en sus primeros ciclos y tengo un problema con el switch y el string porque cuando pongo un capturador de string dentro del Switch este lo ignora y estoy buscando porque lo que me funciono es crear otro Scanner dentro del Switch y ahí si me acepta pero quisiera saber si se puede hacer con solo un Scanner agradezco cualquier ayuda.
Scanner intro = new Scanner (System.in);
        int op, edad, dni[]=new int [1];
        String nomb, apell, corr, direc;
        
        System.out.println("""
                           (1) Cliente
                           (2) Servicios
                           (3) Producto
                           (4) Consultar Citas
                           (5) Pago
                           (6)Cerrar
                           """);
        do {
            System.out.println("Seleccione una opcion: ");
            op=intro.nextInt();
            if (op <= 0 || op > 6) {
                System.out.println("Error...Opcion no valida intente otra vez.");
            }
        } while (op <= 0 || op > 6);
        switch(op){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Ingrese los datos del nuevo paciente");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del paciente: ");
                nomb=intro.nextLine().toUpperCase();
                System.out.println("Ingrese el apellido: ");
                apell=intro.nextLine().toUpperCase();
                do {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese edad: ");
                    edad=intro.nextInt();
                    if (edad < 0) {
                        System.out.println("Error.....edad no reconocida");
                    }
                } while (edad<0);
                
                
                for (int i = 0; i < dni.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese su DNI: ");
                    dni[i]=intro.nextInt();
                }
                
                break;
           case 2:
                
                
        }


Presento mi código para que sea analizado hace poco empecé a tocar arreglos bidimensionales por eso es simple todavía.
Gracias por su saber.

El problema que estas obteniendo se debe al buffer del scanner
Cuando se usa nextInt(), este método no consume la nueva línea (enter) que se introduce al presionar Enter. Por lo tanto, cuando luego llamas a nextLine(), esta llamada lee la nueva línea pendiente en lugar de esperar una nueva entrada del usuario.
Para solucionar este problema sin crear un nuevo Scanner, puedes consumir la nueva línea después de cada entrada numérica (nextInt()) antes de llamar a nextLine() esto se considera "limpiar el buffer del scanner".
Asi es como quedaria el codigo:
Scanner intro = new Scanner(System.in);
        int op, edad;
        int dni[] = new int[1];
        String nomb, apell, corr, direc;

        System.out.println("""
                           (1) Cliente
                           (2) Servicios
                           (3) Producto
                           (4) Consultar Citas
                           (5) Pago
                           (6) Cerrar
                           """);
        do {
            System.out.println("Seleccione una opcion: ");
            op = intro.nextInt();
            if (op <= 0 || op > 6) {
                System.out.println("Error...Opcion no valida intente otra vez.");
            }
        } while (op <= 0 || op > 6);

        intro.nextLine(); // Consumir la nueva línea pendiente

        switch (op) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Ingrese los datos del nuevo paciente");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del paciente: ");
                nomb = intro.nextLine().toUpperCase();
                System.out.println("Ingrese el apellido: ");
                apell = intro.nextLine().toUpperCase();
                do {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese edad: ");
                    edad = intro.nextInt();
                    if (edad < 0) {
                        System.out.println("Error.....edad no reconocida");
                    }
                } while (edad < 0);

                intro.nextLine(); // Consumir la nueva línea pendiente

                for (int i = 0; i < dni.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese su DNI: ");
                    dni[i] = intro.nextInt();
                }

                break;
            case 2:
                // Código para la opción 


Muchas gracias. estuve buscando videos que me explicaran el motivo pero no encontré ninguno.
